# Custom listen ports for Apache not working

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I wanted Apache (v2.4.41) to listen to port 802 and 44302 instead of 80 and 443 on my Ubuntu (v20.04) server so I did the following:

- Edited the port numbers in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. Now the file has just two lines and looks like this:

  ```
  Listen 802
  Listen 44302
  ```
- Edited the port number in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` like this:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:802>
    ....
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Edited the port number in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` like this:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:44302>
      ....
    </VirtualHost>
  </IfModule>
  ```
- Edited the port number in the other virtual hosts inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available` as well.
- Restarted apache
- Confirmed apache is listening to the new ports by using `netstat` as well as `lsof` and got the following:

**netstat:**

```
tcp6       0      0 :::44302         :::*            LISTEN      113959/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::802           :::*            LISTEN      113959/apache2
```

**lsof -i:802**

```
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 113959     root    4u  IPv6 3543809823      0t0  TCP *:802 (LISTEN)
apache2 113960 www-data    4u  IPv6 3543809823      0t0  TCP *:802 (LISTEN)
apache2 113961 www-data    4u  IPv6 3543809823      0t0  TCP *:802 (LISTEN)
```

**lsof -i:44302**

```
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 117939     root    6u  IPv6 3547650042      0t0  TCP *:44302 (LISTEN)
apache2 117940 www-data    6u  IPv6 3547650042      0t0  TCP *:44302 (LISTEN)
apache2 117941 www-data    6u  IPv6 3547650042      0t0  TCP *:44302 (LISTEN)
```

- Confirmed nothing else is listening port 80 and 443 by using both `netstat` and `lsof`.

---

Now when I try to access any of the websites or even the server ip address on port 802, I get a `This site can’t be reached` error. Sites/server ip can be accessed fine on port 44302 however.

- `http://ipaddress:802` OR `http://example.com:802` <---- **DOESN’T WORK**
- `https://ipaddress:44302` OR `https://example.com:44302` <---- **WORKS FINE**

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason port 44302 works but port 802 didn't was because port 44302 is in the range of opened ports in Firewall, while 802 is not.

Ports 0 - 1023 are considered privileged ports and are restricted to the root user unlike the rest of the ports.

Switching the port from 802 to a general port 80 alternative like 8080 fixed the problem.

Comment: I have tried port 8080 and port 3000 but get the same error saying `This site can’t be reached`

Comment: @fahadshaikh Your distribution may have `iptables` enabled by default, in which case you have to explicitely authorize such traffic : `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like apache is listening on ipv6

And in the documentation of apache this is stated

```
If you want httpd to handle IPv4 connections only, regardless of what your platform and APR will support, specify an IPv4 address on all Listen directives, as in the following examples:

Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 192.0.2.1:80
```

Comment: It seems that you may not have a thorough understanding of how binding works, as the OP clearly stated that it was a firewall issue. Your response did not answer the question in any way, and only suggested binding to an IPv4 instead of both.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/577119)